# How to open a page in a table's <td> on clicking on hyperlink from the another <td>

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a table with two columns.  The first column contains the hyperlinks, and on clicking on hyperlink the page should be opened in the second column.

How to do this in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) inside the second column.

Answer (score 0):

pass your URL to be opened to the javascript funcion in hypaerlink onclick event
 **onclick="GoToPage('abc.html')"**

then use  javasript code

```
  function GoToPage(page) { 

    window.open(page);
 }
```